# How can I add a foreign key with hibernate from a table not mapped by hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, apache, hibernate, tomcat

We have a legacy table in our database called "user". It is available to access from every webapp, but it is not mapped by hibernate.

If you create a class (let's call it project) with a column "user_id" and map it with hibernate you cannot reference the user_id of the user table without a User-object mapped by hibernate.

If you had a hibernate-mapped class "**User**" I would do it like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project implements Serializable {

    // project specific attributes go here

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = true, nullable =  false)
    private User user;
}
```

Do you know of a way to create a foreign key relationship without a User-class?  Something like

```
@JoinColumn(table="user",name = "user_id")
private long user_id;
```

Another thought I had was creating a library containing the "user"-class that you could map with hibernate. It would have to be shared through the "libs" folder of the apache tomcat. Only problem is, hibernate seems to fail to map the class if it is used this way. (Mapping works fine, if you import it as normal library to a single web app)

Answer (score 0):

You can map it as `long`

```
@Column(name = "user_id")
private long user_id;
```